# Error enum java

Tags: java

I have this enum

```
public enum Enumerare
{
    DIESEL,BENZINA,NONE
}
```

And I have the class with name "Bicicleta" (in english Bicycle)

```
public class Bicicleta extends Vehicul{

    Enumerare tip;

    public Bicicleta(String serie,Enumerare tip)
    {
        this.tip=NONE;
        this.serie=serie;
    }

}
```

I want to be set only parameter `NONE` for a Bicycle.

Otherwise, if another parameter setting trying to throw an exception of type `NotValideTypeException`.

This is done in the constructor of Bicycle or main program?

However, currently receive this syntax error

> cannot find symbol NONE

Comment: It should be `this.tip=Enumerare.NONE;`

Comment: If a bicycle can only have NONE as its tip, you shouldn't have a tip argument in its constructor. Especially if you completely ignore this argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all bicycles are going to have Enumerare.NONE, there's no reason to have the second parameter of your constructor, as it isn't doing anything.

The reason for your error is that you need to include the enum name with it.

```
this.tip = Enumerare.NONE
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify from which class (enum) `NONE` comes from, so change

```
this.tip = NONE;
```

to

```
this.tip = Enumerare.NONE;
           ^^^^^^^^^ - now compiler knows where it should look for NONE.
```

---

Other option is to use

```
import static your.package.with.Enumerare.*;
```

to import all static members of `Enumerare` and use them freely like

```
this.tip = NONE;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to write `Enumerare.NONE` instead of `NONE`. Also you can try to import your values by a static import.

Answer (score 1):

This is a silly mistake as NONE is not declared in Bicicleta class.

```
this.tip = Enumerare.NONE;
```

This should solve the problem